# How to remove box and whiskers from plot() function in R?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, boxplot

I'm trying to do a very simple plot using the plot() function in R where I plot out the weights and diets of chicks in a stratified plot. For other simple plots like this I've been able to just use the plot() function and it's gone fine. But for some reason, R insists on plotting this as a box-and-whiskers chart instead of plotting all the values themselves. I've tried many different solutions I've found on the Web, from box=FALSE to box=0 to bty="n" to type="p" but nothing works. R always plots it as a box-and-whiskers chart. I can use whisklty=0 to get rid of the whiskers, but nothing I've tried (including all possible combinations of the above solutions) will replace the boxes with the actual values I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the x-axis data is categorical, `plot` will return a boxplot by default. You could run `plot.default()` instead of `plot()` and that will give you a plot of points.

Compare, for example:

```
plot(iris$Species, iris$Petal.Width)

plot.default(iris$Species, iris$Petal.Width)
```

If you type `methods(plot)` in the console, you'll see all of the different kinds of plots the `plot` function returns, depending on what type of object you give it. `plot.default` is the "method" that gets dispatched when you provide `plot` with two columns of numbers. `plot.factor` gets dispatched when the y-values are numeric and the x-values are categorical (run `?plot.factor` for details). If you do `plot(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl))` the `plot.table` method gets dispatched. And so on.

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly! Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as the question is old enough for me to. I'm surprised I couldn't find this answer on here somewhere already; seems like such an obvious problem to run into